# SQL Azure Remote Procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We are trying to execute a remote procedure on an Azure database :

```
INSERT INTO #temp (
    ConsultantId
    ,UserId
    ,Name
    ,Email
    ,Phone
    ,DefaultContact
    )
EXEC @RemoteResult = sp_execute_remote @RemoteSource
    ,@SQLString
    ,@ParmDefinition
    ,@userid = @userid;
```

Where #temp is a table with the same 6 columns as shown in the insert above.

However, we always get the **$ShardName** column returned even if we specify only the columns we need and as a result we also get the following error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the full statement. You say you get the column `$ShardName` back, which means that you're asking for that value in your parameter `@SQLString` (which we can't see).

Comment: Just make the temp table match the columns returned.

Comment: @Larnu. This is the statement: SET SQLString = N'SELECT ConsultantId, UserId, Name, Email, Phone,DefaultContact FROM SalesPersons where UserId=@userid'; - No mention of $ShardName.

Comment: @Nick. You cannot create a Table with a column name starting with $.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE MyTable ([$ShardName] VARCHAR(100))`. It doesn't need the same name it just needs the same datatype and the same number of columns

Comment: 1. I ran that exact script and it created the column fine 2. If I had an answer I would post an answer not a comment.

Comment: @Nick. My apologies. It did not work at first but it is now. Many Thanks.

Comment: If you solved it can you write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the solution to this problem is to simply add another column to the table to accept the [`$Shard]` column. It need to be in the right position and needs to have the correct data type. It doens't need the same name.

For clarity, it's worth creating it with the same name though.

Assuming `$Shard` was the final column from the proc, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO #temp (
    ConsultantId
    ,UserId
    ,Name
    ,Email
    ,Phone
    ,DefaultContact
    ,[$Shard]
    )
EXEC @RemoteResult = sp_execute_remote @RemoteSource
    ,@SQLString
    ,@ParmDefinition
    ,@userid = @userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding relevant documentation

[sp_execute_remote (Azure SQL Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-remote-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current)

`sp_execute_remote adds an additional column to the result set named '$ShardName' that contains the name of the remote database that produced the row.`